# Functional Languages + Algorithmic Trading

Tags: functional-programming, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading

Is anyone knowledgeable on programming language implementation of algorithmic trading?

I am going to propose a research project on functional programming and algorithmic trading.
My proposal is here: http://pastebin.com/wcigd5tk
Any comments would be very appreciated.

What do you think the future of functional languages in the financial field is? I see many job postings that ask for experience in java and C++, and i dont understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jane Street](http://www.janestreet.com/) is very well known for using OCaml for their trading software. [Here](http://www.janestreet.com/technology/ocaml.php) you can find some reasons why they decided to use functional languages rather than imperative ones. They also have a blog describing several specific solutions to problems they encountered during development.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is the most popular in that field.
java , python ,haskall ,c# are all runners up

haskall and c# are functional with haskell being purely functional

eventually the field will move to a more "modern language" like c# or haskall but right now c++ has so much support the libraries are already made and its implementation is the easiest .

Comment: http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=10&threadid=63684&FTVAR_MSGDBTABLE= 

heres a good fourm discussion on haskell

Answer (score 1):

For Trading application, it usually has `Real time, multithread, low latency, high availability` to consider too. I was working in a company developing a trading application using both(mixed) C++ and Java as it fit with the behaviour of the application.